# Can I set up a second 401(k) at my LLC?

Tags: united-states, 401k, self-employment, limited-liability-company, limits

I have a 401(k) at work.  I also have an LLC.  Can I start a second 401(k) and contribute an additional $16,500?

Answer (score 5):

You can have multiple 401(k), but the $16500 maximum is per person, not per account.

Comment: I don't know about the rules when you combine them, but an Individual 401(k) account at the LLC could have a limit **substantially** higher than $16500 -- $49000 if your LLC's profit sharing can support it: http://www.solo401kcontributionlimits.com/

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but be aware of the following limits, which apply across *all accounts* (*not* on a per-account basis):

- You, as the **employee**, can contribute up to **$16,500**
- Your company, as the **employer**, can contribute up to **25%** of your compensation
- The **combined** employee and employer contribution may not exceed **$49,000**
- If you are **over age 50**, you are entitled to an **additional $5,500** "catch-up" contribution
- The total amount of your contribution cannot exceed your total compensation

(Limits apply for 2011)

Keep in mind that you can also contribute up to $5,000 to an IRA -- however, unlike the 401(k) contribution, it will not be tax-deductable.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can deposit into a SEP IRA, 20% of income up to $45k if I recall correctly.

(Wow, $45K was so 2007, it's up to $49K this year 2011)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to raise your contribution ceiling a bit, you may also invest in a personal Roth IRA up to $5K a year in addition to maxing out your 401(k).  It is my understanding that the same is not true of a traditional IRA.